# I have a 10 jugs...( A problem at combinatorics)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the first jug we have 2 red balls and 2 white balls. In each of the other jugs we have at 4 red balls and 4 white balls.
We take a random ball from the first one and put it at the second jug, then we take a random ball from the second jug and put it on the third...

The question is: **What is the probability that we will get a red ball at the 10th jug?** (i.e. the last ball that we have taken randomly is from the 10th jug).

I got $\frac{1}{4}$, is it right?

How did I get it? We prove that if all that jugs have same amount of red balls and the same amount of white balls (each one), the probability to get red ball in the first one is equal to the probability to get red ball from the last one.
So, I divide the jugs into two groups: The first jug and the others jugs.
Then I said:
$E$ = we pull out white ball from the first jug.
$F$=  we pull out red ball from the second jug.
$$P(F)=P(F|E)\cdot P(E)+P(F|E^C)\cdot P(E^C)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{4}{9}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{5}{9}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\\= \frac19 + \frac{5}{36}=\frac{9}{36}=\frac{1}{4}$$
Am I right? or did I make mistakes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer with simple proof: $\frac{1}{2}$. Notice that the entire situation is symmetric. Everything happens with the same probability to white as it does to red. Thus $P(Red)=P(white)=\frac{1}{2}$

What's wrong with your answer:
"We prove that if all that jugs have same amount of red balls and the same amount of white balls (each one), the probability to get red ball in the first one is equal to the probability to get red ball from the last one."

This is great, and if you prove this you are done and get $\frac{1}{2}$ as your answer. You don't successfully do this. To do this you would want to end up at $P(F)=\frac{1}{2}$ not $\frac{1}{4}$, because you had a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of pulling a red ball out of the first jug. What you are saying is that you go from a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance to a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance, not stay the same. I'm not sure where the extra $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from in your equations. $P(F|E)=\frac{4}{9}$ and $P(E^C)=\frac{1}{2}$. Yet you have a second factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in that term. Same with the other term, take those out and it will add up to $\frac{1}{2}$ like it should.

Comment: Thank you! but how to you get that $P(F|E)=\frac{4}{5}$?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should read $\frac{4}{9}$. If you take a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ out of your equation you get the right answer. I just miscopied. Fixing.

Comment: Thank you!! Now it's clear!!

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously $\frac{1}{2}$, due to the symmetry in the problem : if you paint all white balls red and all red balls white, this is the same problem, so the probability of getting a red ball is equal to the probability to get a white ball.